# how to delete particular number or letter before an symbols (|) using grep command

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have N number of sequence in a file like this

```
>668|CAX10446 conserved hypothetical protein 
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRRSSATRATESRSSSRTARGASSGYKEYSPSAAR

>669|CAX10447 conserved protein 
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRRSSATRATESRSSSRTARGASSGYKEYSPSAAR
```

or like this

```
>gi|76167242|gb|AAX50250.1| hypothetical protein CTA_0001 
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRR
```

Now, I need a `grep` command to delete a particular word or number in first line.

Output should be:

```
>CAX10446 conserved hypothetical protein 
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRRSSATRATESRSSSRTARGASSGYKEYSPSAAR
```

or

```
>AAX50250.1| hypothetical protein CTA_0001 [Chlamydia trachomatis A/HAR-13]
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRRSSATRAAESRS
SSRTARGASSGYREYSPSAAR
```

I need a grep command to do this action, I used `sed` but it removed the first line, the ID, so it's difficult to identify which sequence is which.

Comment: No, you don't want `grep`, it's the wrong tool for the job. `grep` can't modify your files. Please [edit] your question and explain what part of the ID line you need removed.  Do you want to remove everything before the last `|`? How can we know what to remove?

Comment: Hi All, Thank you.. I just want to remove the character before "|". I just fount out .. I used "sed 's/^.*|/|/' B_304.txt >n.txt" . It gave me proper out put.. thanks

Comment: That won't give you the right output for your second example. It will only leave ` hypothetical protein CTA_0001 `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to remove everything before the last `|` character. However, your second example has a `|` after the ID and before the `hypothetical protein`. Presumably, in that case, you want to remove everything before the last `|` that is not followed by a space.

Here's one way:

```
$ sed 's/| / /; s/^[^ ]*|/>/' file.pep 
>CAX10446 conserved hypothetical protein 
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRRSSATRATESRSSSRTARGASSGYKEYSPSAAR
>AAX50250.1 hypothetical protein CTA_0001 
MSIRGVGGNGNSRIPSHNGDGSNRRSQNTKNKVEDRVRSLYSSRSNENRESPYAVVDVSSMIESTPTSGE
TTRASRGVFSRFQRGLGRVADKVRRAVQRAWSSVSIRR
```

The `s/| / /;` removes any `|` followed by a space. This will remove the `|` from `AAX50250.1|`. The `s/^[^ ]*|/>/` looks for a `>` at the beginning of the line (`^>`) and removes the longest string of non-space (`[^ ]`) characters until the last `|` on the line.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! it was help full.  I used sed 's/^.*|AAX/|AAX/' CHT_A.fasta >B.txt

Comment: @Nitha you're welcome. If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Terdon..yes your command worked perfectly! i did

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with grep. 
You should read 3 line after each empty line and copy it to variable.
You should cut last part of variable.

The parser will do;

First `reverse` string

Second `cut` string with `|` and get first

Third `reverse` string

```
echo $yourstring |rev |cut -d'|' -f1|rev
```

BTW this will not remove, only shows you the part. If you want to save output redirect it to file.

```
echo $yourstring |rev |cut -d'|' -f1|rev > yournewfile
```

Comment: Thank you Terdon! your command worked perfectly sed 's/| / /; s/^[^ ]*|/>/'. and Thanks Yavuzs for helping me to use grep, i will try..